# asp.net core mvc 2.1 return a populated model to browser and lost all fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In the Create action of the controller, based on user input, we plan to populate the model object with some data, to minimize data entry:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Item item, string str)
{
    // if only str is provided
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.KeyInfo) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        Helpers.FillItemModel(item, str);   //fill data
    }
    else if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(item);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
    }

    return View(item);
}
```

However, although we can confirm the item object has been populated with data to several fields, by setting break point at the last line: `return View(item)`, when the browser gets the response, all fields are empty.

But if we comment out the entire code segment, only leave the return statement and do a post with some data that was manually entered, the browser will receive correct data in all fields.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update `ModelState` value you have to reset the `ModelState` first as follows:

```
// if only str is provided
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.KeyInfo) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
 {
    ModelState.Clear();
    Helpers.FillItemModel(item, str);   //fill data
 }
```

`ModelState.Clear()` will reset the whole model. If you don't want that and just want to update few fields value keeping other field value intact then use `ModelState["fieldName"].Value = "newValue` in your helper class.